# prolem on restarting apache after trying with invoice ninja

Tags: php, mysql, apache, invoice-ninja

I got a problem on **restaring apache2** after configuring all the thing regarding **invoice ninja** **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNO5q2gwCTA**

Comment: Please go read [ask]. What you want to know needs to be described directly inside your question. Use your _words_, instead of just pointing us to a video uploaded somewhere externally.

Comment: OK i will follow here after

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used Virtual Host, I think there lies the problem. By default you will have /etc/apache2/sites-available make sure the apache2 is pointing to the virtual host that you have created ininja.conf.

By default apache2 points to 000-default.conf. Since you want to point to new ininja.conf its not point.

So how to fix this is use the following commands to stop the service of 000-default.cof and start ininja.conf

```
sudo a2ensite ininja.conf

sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

Make sure to restart your apache2

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fine i got the result but  i want some more that how to identify the invoice laravel codes to edit. Is there is any website to quick understand or any shortcuts to understand.

Comment: thsnk you for your answer

Comment: Hey @srinivasan good to know that it helped you. Can you please accept the answer by checking the tick mark. So that even it will benifit others.

Comment: @srinivasan Even I have just started with Laravel. I highly suggest you to go through their documentation. Its the best one

Comment: Ok I am new for stackoverflow. Here after i will follow that